# Are academic groups allowed to use grant funds to hedge against exchange rate changes?

Tags: united-states, funding, united-kingdom

If an academic group receives a multi-year grant denominated in a currency different from that that they pay salaries, can they use some of the grant to hedge against changes in the relative value of the two currencies?

Some years ago I was a member of a group in the UK that received a substantial five year grant from the US.  Between the awarding of the grant and the time we started employing staff the pound dropped against the dollar, meaning we could have employed more staff than we originally estimated.  However, because of the risk that the exchange rate reversed over the time of the grant the "bean counters" did not let us take this option.  In the end the pound remained somewhat low and we had excess money in the grant in the final year.  The project could have been much more productive if that money had been spent on more staff in the beginning.

If this was a private company they would have the option of hedging the risk, ie. taking some position on the currency markets such that whatever the exchange rate does the money available would be roughly similar.  Is an academic group allowed to take such a futures position in the forex markets?

While I am not in this situation at the moment, considering the substantial drop in the value of the pound that has occurred since the July NIH funding round I suspect many people are, and the magnitude of the change is much greater than has occurred in recent years.

Comment: Ask your funding agency.

Comment: I have never heard of a funding agency which would allow 'bets' on the currency markets (or stocks, bonds, etc). Not to mention it would need to be the organisation holding the funds to make these transactions. So either the funding body or University would need to have an account with access to the money markets and be willing to manage these investments (with the associated administrative/tax implications).

Comment: Profit and non-profit endeavors have different goals, money management and corresponding regulations. It is not only about “i wish i can do this or that”.

Comment: I am sure you would have complained against public "bean counters" being unproductive if the project would have incurred a loss because of GBP getting stronger against the USD.
Reg "If this was a private company": you are welcome to focus your question to the numerous american universities that are private bodies.

Comment: Think of the headlines if your hedge loses.  "Rogue academic squanders taxpayer funds speculating in currency markets."  In such a case, the grant agency would want to be able to say to the public "that was totally unauthorized and we are suing them for the losses, oh and by the way banning their institution from receiving grants for ten years".  So no, I don't think they'll allow it.

Comment: @NateEldredge You do get that in the proposed if case your hedge loses your salary/grant award "wins", and the project is in the same situation as if the hedge had "won", or if it was a wash.

Comment: Most comments and the first answer miss the point that the proposed hedging is not a plan to invest and hope for an increase in funds but to *eliminate* the risk of changes in the currency exchange rate (up or down!) This is a common thing when one has costs in currency X but gets paid in currency Y. https://www.rbcgam.com/en/ca/learn-plan/investment-strategies/what-is-currency-hedging/detail

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd be pretty sure that this won't be possible/allowed. But any answer should address the actual plan and not argue against speculating with grants to turn them into bigger grants. The specific issue are 1) Such a hedge will cost money (just like buying insurance). Where will the money come from? 2) Logistical/legal obstacles to actually implement the hedge.

Comment: @user2705196 Your analogy answers your own question. Insurance is certainly a legit expense and may even be required by law (i.e. employee and public liability). The money comes from the indirect cost slice of the grant, just like say, toilet paper for the bathrooms.

Comment: @user2705196 sure, but this does not match with OP sentence "The project could have been much more productive if that money had been spent on more staff in the beginning.". That's not "hedging", that is "the free lunch exists only when it is to my advantage" .

Comment: @EarlGrey If the currency have changed enough between award and hiring for you to afford say 6 more FTE/years if the rate stayed low, then one could hedge the risk and employ 1 FTE for 5 years without a risk of running out of money.  The way it happened to me was that there was money left over in the final year when employing 6 FTE's for one year was neither possible or useful.  It is exactly as user2705196 states.

Comment: @User65535  "say 6 more FTE/years". Let's not speak about spherical staff or other unrealistic assumption, please. A posteriori is easy to say "if the rate stayed low". How likely was the rate to stay low? how do you weight the risk? there is no way that you can conflate "hedging currency risk" directly with "having more money to hire staff". I am sure if those were OP's money on which their living depends, OP would not come out with such an idea.

Comment: @EarlGrey This is exactly what I would do with my own money, and it is what many rich people and businesses do with their money.  It is common practice to manage the risk of forex changes.  The likelihood of the rate staying look is decided by the financial markets, the bet is structured such that the money available is the same whatever the exchange rate does.

Comment: I think a lot of the people responding here are getting hung up on your use of the word "bet". A hedge is a financial transaction made to reduce your exposure to some risk rather than to increase it; it is not a bet, nor is it generally imprudent in the way that betting, gambling or speculating is generally considered to be. You might get better responses if you remove the word "bet" from your question.

Comment: In this scenario you *have* enough money to employ more people, and you risk *losing* that money, so insuring it is perfectly responsible (though that doesn't mean the funding body would necessarily allow it). From another perspective, the reason you *have* more money than you expected to have is because you were exposed to exchange rate risk, which could have gone in the other direction and crippled the project, so one might say the project's finances were being mismanaged by not hedging the exchange rate risk sooner.

Comment: @User65535 please stop using the word *bet* if you are talking about financial risks. It shows a deeply wrong attitude. On top of that, I do not care about what *rich* people are doing, nor about being rich, because here we are not discussing how to preserve wealth, but fundings to run projects, which is more similar to investing on the first of the month the money you need to pay rent&food on the last day of the month, not your savings.

Comment: @EarlGrey That is a perfect analogy.  If the exchange rate was likely to change significantly between one getting paid in a currency and paying your rent in another currency then taking a futures position in the forex markets (more characters than bet ;) ) to hedge the risk would be a rational decision.

Comment: @User65535 " If the exchange rate was likely to change significantly" All good, thanks for the discussion.

Comment: Honestly this is a pretty good idea whenever research groups deal with grants not of their native country. De-risking the grant money is a very different intention than merely speculation.

Answer (score 21):

As usual, it is impossible to answer questions of the form of "is XYZ allowed with grants?" with certainty - the answer to any question like this will always be *"that depends on the rules of the organization providing the grant as well as on the rules of the organization receiving / managing the grant".*

That said, for this specific question I feel fairly confident to say that universities will generally *not* allow you to speculate with grant money, or invest them in the financial market in some other manner. Grants are given for specific purposes (this makes them different from, say, donations) - sometimes these purposes may be abstractly formulated, but never sufficiently abstractly that "invest it in some other company" would be covered. At the end of the day, if an organization gives you money to (for example) hire grad students you actually need to hire grad students - not invest the money, hope for higher returns, and then hire even more grad students (or alternatively hire less or no grad students if the investment goes bad).

> However, because of the risk that the exchange rate reversed over the time of the grant the "bean counters" did not let us take this option. In the end the pound remained somewhat low and we had excess money in the grant in the final year.

Realistically, stories like this are the exact reason why grants (even personal grants) are usually submitted to universities to manage and not directly to researchers - the "bean counters" as you call them are sufficiently experienced (and sufficiently disinterested in the outcome of any specific project) to make objective financial decisions that do not get the project, university, or PI into troubles, whereas we scientists may sometimes get *a little* carried away with positive possibilities without considering the risks.

Comment: Hedging is the opposite of a speculative "bet"; see [user2705196's comment under the question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/509973).  My understanding is that with hedging to cover the risk of the exchange returning to the old value, in the worst case they could still spend more GBP than if they'd effectively converted all the grant money at the start (at the worse exchange rate).  If the exchange rate goes back up, their hedge "wins" and provides the extra GBP.  If not, then it loses but the favourable exchange rate means they still have enough GBP to cover it + salaries.

Comment: -1 The question is effectively just asking whether the researchers have to convert USD to GBP immediately, or whether they can wait until they need the money.

Comment: @user253751 Usually you don't "have" that money beforehand, though. You get it in tranches, either at the start or the end of a year. So the university would need to buy the respective amount of USD at the beginning of the grant period. I'm not sure why that wouldn't be, or at the very least be perceived as, a forex speculation. That you do  it to hedge some other risks will not make a real difference, in my opinion.

Comment: Hedging is equivalent to being concerned your lab may burn down and buying insurance against that event. Would it be inappropriate to buy insurance with grant money?

Comment: @RichardTingle Yes, it would, because the institution already handles such insurance arrangements. For all we (and the OP) know, they likewise have some sort risk mitigation plans for exchange rate fluctuations.  If they do, then the last thing they want is for individual PIs to be buying their own, likely redundant, insurance, especially if those PIs don't have any particular expertise in such things.

Answer (score 13):

Though I'm in the US and not the UK, my impression that in both places **academic groups do not handle money, their institutions do**.

US government grants, in particular, are always to the institution. The PI and other staff don't have any authority to spend the money directly, it's up to the institution to manage the money. In your case, the institution decided to be conservative and did not let the group spend more pounds early in the grant than were originally budgeted. An alternative might be to make exchanged funds available on an annual basis (or whatever schedule the funds are actually received on). I could see that as a potential challenge if you work in a place where the employer has restrictions on when they can release paid staff: if you can't drop an employee tomorrow that you're paying today, you have to be sure you'll have the money to pay them tomorrow, too.

Large universities have their own financial clout and though there may be some restrictions on those operating as public entities (which would vary by jurisdiction), academic institutions manage their money much like a company does, through investments and relevant hedges in their endowments, retirement funds, etc.

Answer (score 11):

From the guidelines for grant applications at https://www.ukri.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/BBSRC-051020-Funding-opp-20ALERTJustificationOfResourcesDoc.docx:

> If quotes are provided in foreign currency the exchange rate used to
> convert it to GBP should be clearly stated. The exchange rate at time
> of submission should be used, BBSRC-UKRI cannot account for changes in
> exchange rate between submission and award of the grant.

It's not clear whether this applies to funding from all the UK Research Councils, or just from BBSRC.

Comment: That's interesting but it doesn't really address the question.

Comment: @psmears It seems to me to be a pretty clear "no" to the question as asked, for the grants to which it applies.

Comment: No, that's a document saying how to justify what you're going to spend money on, and it's saying they won't adjust your grant if the exchange rate changes between them accepting your grant application and you needing to purchase something in foreign currency. It doesn't say you _can't_ purchase a hedging contract (and nor does it say you can).

Answer (score 1):

**Explicitly hedging** as in financial institutions? No. I would be surprised if any grant funder or fundee would allow that.

**Are potential currency fluctuations taken into account** when writing and executing on grants? At least sometimes, if they are done well and involve multiple currencies.

This could include:

- moving work between partners

  - e.g. having a UK group do an expensive experiment and the US lab doing a cheaper one
- bringing expenses forward or back in time

  - e.g. buying equipment now even if it won't be used immediately
- changing currencies of purchased goods and/or services

  - e.g. paying a subcontractor in a third country to build a website with dollars instead of pounds
  - e.g. moving a conference/meeting venue to a country with a favourable currency

That's not "hedging" in the forex sense, but it is building options into the structure of the project to react to future currency movements.

Even without currency fluctuations, research is by nature uncertain; the [1000 Genomes project](https://www.sanger.ac.uk/news_item/2010-10-27-1000-genomes-project-publishes-analysis-of-completed-pilot-phase/) ended up with about 2,500 genomes for example, partly because the technology got cheaper to run faster than expected over the course of the project (and currency was probably a part of that).

Answer (score 1):

Professional "bean counter" aka "research administrator" here with 12 years' experience at top US research universities, having managed funds at more than 20 US Federal agencies and dozens of industry sponsors and foundations.

Your question sounds inflammatory, but it actually is a good question on how income is allowed to be handled. There are regulations in the US about how income is allowed to be distributed (i.e., can the institution get it up front and also keep it). I have seen some private agencies allow us to keep the interest on our income, and at my institution it goes back to the PI when the grant ends. I know of one foundation that required us to refund the interest to them and any interest we received on unused funds! (Why did we accept such a stupid grant??)

The way the feds get around this entire question is by not giving the money upfront. Because Uniform Guidance pushes the cost reimbursable model, there is no interest to worry about.  There are however federal accounts that also give fixed price, often via SBIR/STTR mechanisms.

The way many academics handle uncertainty in funding is to run a deficit upfront, but this carries certain risks. Let's say you have a startup of $1M.  You can overspend year 1 funding on many (most?) federal grants knowing the deficit carries forward nearly always. However, let's say your contract is with IARPA and they aren't interested in Phase 2 funding. They cancel the project and you are out of pocket on your over-expenditure. Not a lot of PIs can gamble on such levels, but it happens at top institutions from time to time.

If you need to start spending before a contract is in place, many institutions call this an "advance account". Depending on funding this may or may not be controversial. I work with CS and Engineering right now and with MURI funding I always run a deficit to ensure we get our next increment and expense for the costs we have today. I usually am more worried about underspend than overspend. This is frequently because PIs don't ramp up their spend right away, we end up behind enough to lose the next increment. Most agencies want less than 25% remaining to award more. I can implement this strategy because I'm at a top school. Other places can't do this and uncertainty is a real problem, sometimes with no solutions.

My request to all PIs with US federal funding is to read all terms and conditions (NIH has the Grants Policy Statement; NSF has the PAPPG) including the larger federal Uniform Guidance for grants and FAR for contracts. If researchers took an interest in the rules, my job would be much easier. A lot of these questions are answered therein. Look into "carry forward" or "carryover" rules. Running a deficit is an actual strategy if your institution allows it (see above-mentioned risk).

Answer (score -1):

Any organization that accepts a grant receives a check or transfer from the funding organization.  The organization has rules on how that money is to be spent.  Indeed, grants are considered projects.

The institution is effectively saying "in exchange for this much money, our investigator will do the research described in the grant."  Either periodically, or at the end of the contract, the funding institution checks up on things to make sure things are going as planned.  If the institution has real problems with interim reports, the next check may never come.

Obviously, research being research, not all of it works out, and institutes are fine with this.  Institutes *will not* be fine with a report that says "yeah, I know you gave us $250,000 USD, but we tried to leverage that into $350,000 USD by speculation, and it failed, so we were only able to spend the $125,000 that we were able to recover". The institute does not expect you to spend money they didn't give you (unless part of the contract was matching funds, or some such), but they expect you to make reasonable efforts to spend the money they do give you the way you said you would.

Taking the money given to the Uni and putting it in some account for speculative pursuits is most likely not allowed.  In fact, I suspect criminal charges could be the result.

Let's take this out another step.  Say you have $250K in an account for a grant.  You think "Wow, I can speculate with that money, make a ton, and then return the $250K!!"  I suggest this isn't all that much different to a prosecuting attorney from your original scenario.

UPDATE:
FWIW, such costs are unallowable for NIH research grants:
From https://grants.nih.gov/grants/policy/nihgps/html5/section_7/7.9_allowability_of_costs_activities.htm

> Contingency Provisions
> Unallowable. Payments made by the NIH awarding
> IC to the non-Federal entity's "contingency reserve" or any similar
> payment made for events the occurrence of which cannot be foretold
> with certainty as to the time or intensity, or with an assurance of
> their happening, are unallowable under non-construction grants.
> Contingency funds do not include pension funds, self-insurance funds,
> and normal accruals (also see Reserve Funds in this exhibit). (See
> also Construction Grants-Allowable and Unallowable Costs and
> Activities in IIB concerning contingency funds under construction
> grants).

Indemnification, though, is permitted under some circumstances, which I'm not sure would be met here.

Comment: Hedging is the opposite of a speculative "bet"; see [user2705196's comment under the question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/509973).  My understanding is that with hedging to cover the risk of the exchange returning to the old value, in the worst case they could still spend more GBP than if they'd effectively converted all the grant money at the start (at the worse exchange rate).  If the exchange rate goes back up, their hedge "wins" and provides the extra GBP.  If not, then it loses but the favourable exchange rate means they still have enough GBP to cover it + salaries.

Comment: @PeterCordes -- it still "some bet on the currency markets", in the asker's own language, and can certainly lose value when you bet the wrong way.  Change the example I used of $250K becoming $125K to $250K becoming $225K, and the story is largely unchanged.  "Hedging" in this case still means gambling with other people's money.  If a university feels like they can find a way to make that work for them, God bless 'em.  If I found out about a faculty member to do this on their own, I'd be on the phone to the relevant chairs within moments.  People get fired over stuff like that.

Comment: Sure, that comment is a reasonable answer.  It's a lot less obvious than the way your actual answer is written.  i.e. that hedging isn't a perfect guarantee, and in the worst case you can still lose some.  That sounds like the key point, instead of talking about wild speculation or leveraging hoping for a big *gain*.  Also, it's ongoing funding, not a lump sum of $250K already sitting in an account; the whole point is that the future years of funding are already in a different currency from the salaries, and the exchange rate could fluctuate whether you hedge or not.

Comment: What if it was "Yeah, I know you gave us £200,000 worth of USD, but we didn't exchange it straight away and it was only £100,000 by the time we exchanged it"?

Comment: The amount of a typical NIH RO1 is about a quarter mill a year, when you count indirects, and every year, a quarter mill indeed gets put into an account, so that number was carefully chosen, and not in the least hyperbolic.  Further under audit, it won't make any difference which type of approach the investment attempt uses.  The unauthorized use of the funds can still cause a world of hurt for the people that made it happen.

Comment: Money is fungible. If my grant is $250k, it gets stuck in a big university-wide pot. The gains from that pot become unrestricted funds. On the other hand, losses from that pot can be made up with unrestricted funds (endowments, general donations). Or perhaps it gets covered by other people's money which hasn't been spent yet, much like a bank. As long as, in the end, $250k was spent on allowable expenses, the government can't tell the difference and is satisfied.

Comment: @user71659. That's not universally true.  My school holds the funds quite separate, and there are expense categories the grant accounts cannot be used to pay.  I think many US schools use such practices.  Also, money earned by the endowment may or may not be unrestricted.

Comment: @ScottSeidman You're getting two things confused: while schools may have "account" codes, and allowable expenses to charge to each code, there is absolutely no requirement not to commingle unspent funds. Obviously, your institution is holding the cash at some bank or [in investments](https://www.ucop.edu/investment-office/investment-funds/stip/index.html), and that's the "pot". This is like a bank, you have an account in your view, but all your money is commingled with other customers' at the bank's account at the Federal Reserve, and a large fraction of the money doesn't even exist as cash.

Comment: @ScottSeidman: Currency hedging is not an "investment attempt". Typically one purchases a contract that basically says "Bank X agrees to change up to N dollars into pounds at rate R% at any time over the next Y years". While one should definitely clear the purchase of such a contract with both the institution and the funder before entering into it, it is in many cases prudent step, in much the same way as having insurance, and hence the institution and funder may consider it a good idea.

Comment: @psmears: But like insurance premiums, there is a cost to purchase such an option contract.  And "purchasing option contracts" is likely not one of the permitted use of the funds, so some other funds would have to be allocated from some discretionary/flexible pool.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Right, that's why I said you'd have to clear it with the funder & institution. (And if the funder's not happy but the institution is, then using other funds available to the institution would indeed be a solution.)

Comment: @BenVoigt "Forex trading" is also probably not one of the permitted uses of grant money, and yet you're allowed to exchange it for your own currency...